# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) and -lLIB_d_classic-NOTFOUND

Tags: terminal, clang, gnu-make

So I very not familiar with computer, but I am facing some problem with recompiling an open software call openCARP. I tried to input "cmake --build _build" in the terminal in the openCARP folder, but it came out some error. So what should I do? I am currently using macOS

The output:

```
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable bin/openCARP
ld: library not found for -lLIB_d_classic-NOTFOUND
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencarp-bin.dir/build.make:122: bin/openCARP] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:321: CMakeFiles/opencarp-bin.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2`
```

What should I type in the terminal to solve this problem?